# Javascript - Change button onclick to an existing function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button:

```
<button onclick = "doDisactivate(5);" id = "status_button_5" value = "Disactivate" />
```

where 5 is a dynamically added ID. I have two javascript functions, doDisactivate(ID) and doActivate(5).

```
function doDisactivate(serviceID) {
    // logic that changes the button onclick to doActivate(serviceID)
}

function doActivate(serviceID) {
    // logic that changes the button onclick to doActivate(serviceID)
}
```

I'm guessing I can do the following with jquery:

```
${"#status_button_" + serviceID}.click(function() {
    doActivate(serviceID);
});
```

But is there a way to directly assign the function while passing the ID as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you aren't using jquery event bindings, you could use `$("#status_button_5").attr("onclick", "doActivate(5);")` to directly change the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Are event bindings better? What do they add?

Comment: It's just easier to work with. For example, you could do something like `var activated = false; $("#status_button_5").on("click", function(){ if(activated){doDisactivate(5);} else {doActivate(5);} activated = !activated; })`.

Answer (score 1):

do something like this

```
${"#status_button_" + serviceID}.click(function(event) {
    doActivate(event.target.id);
});
```

or

```
onClick="doDisactivate(this.id)"
```

Comment: This works, but I want the function directly, not through another anonymous function.

Comment: you can add the event parameter to you doActivate function, and within the function, call `event.target.id`.